# how to redirect to another page using innerhtml in c#

Tags: c#, innerhtml

I am trying redirect to another page using below code

```
divIRSPayment.InnerHtml = divIRSPayment.InnerHtml
    + "Your Tax amount is $ "+lblBalance.Text
    + "<br />Click here to enter <a href='IRSEFWPayment.aspx'>IRS Payment Details</a>";
```

I have written above code in back-end. The amount is displaying successfully and text is also displaying successfully. But when i click on **IRS Payment Details** link, it is not redirecting to another page instead page is getting reloaded and displaying same page.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need to use absolute URL of the file rather than just the file name. Something like below using [`Page.ResolveUrl()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.resolveurl.aspx) method

```
".....<a href='" + Page.ResolveUrl("~/IRSEFWPayment.aspx") + "'>"
```

Comment: no not working sry...... it is not showing error also just when we click on page will reload and again display same page.......... it is not redirecting